# Change default text editor

Tags: linux

I want to change the default text editor of my Linux to sublime text 3 (when double click on a file).

I tried to add those lines in my bashrc but it doesn't work :

```
export EDITOR="sublimetext"
export VISUAL="sublimetext"
```

Thanks

Comment: this depends on your desktop environment settings, not on env variables

Comment: also try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, EDITOR is used by, e.g. `less` when browsing a file and pressing 'v'. "Double click on a file" would be a Gnome/KDE/whatever thing.

Comment: What's your desktop? KDE, Gnome, Unity ?